# Finding the total number of proper subfields of $F$?

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I was thinking about the following problem:

> Let $F$ be a field with $5^{12}$ elements.Then how can I find the total number of proper subfields of $F$?

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Did you mean proper *subfields*? If not, what is *proper field of $F$*?

Comment: I am sorry,sir.It is just typo.I have edited  my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it you mean, proper subfield.

Can you show that any subfield of $F$ contains the field of $5$ elements?

Can you show that any subfield must contain $5^r$ elements, for some $r$?

Can you show that the degree of such a subfield (over the field of $5$ elements) must be $r$? and must be a divisor of the degree of the field of $5^{12}$ elements?

Can you show that a finite field has at most one subfield of any given number of elements?

If you can do all those, you have your answer.

Comment: I have got my answer,sir.Thanks a lot.

Comment: The answer, btw, must be 4...

Comment: @Don, that's not the answer I got.

Comment: Well, the number of proper divisors of $\,12\,$ is $\,4\,$, isn't it? I mean, $\,2,3,4,6\,$...unless I missed some other.

Comment: @Don, I'm counting $1$ as a proper divisor. $1$ is trivial-but-proper, $12$ is nontrivial-but-improper.

Comment: I guess that's a matter of definition or of wording, and I'm really not sure.

Comment: @user120386, 12 has 6 divisors, 5 of them proper. Why do you think the answer is 4?

Comment: Gerry Myerson : I am sorry, I am editting my post.

Comment: We know that if a finite field F has characteristic p (prime), then F has cardinality pr where r=[F:Fp]. So r is a divisor of 12. I think proper subfield of $F$ is atmost 5.

Answer (score 0):

The number of divisors of 12 are 1,2,3,4,6,12
Therefore 6=subfields exists.
Proper subfield means except 12 then number of proper subfield of 5^12 is 5.

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! I suggest to write more details in your answer. Note also, the site has Latex formatting, type in `$5^{12}$` and you will get $5^{12}$.